# Flash Presentation Navigation

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I designed a flash slide show on AS2, I want to navigate throw the slides with keyboard keys left and right  (back and forth).

I appreciate your advice,

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using actionscript 2 and not 3. Just currious. To answer your question You will need to use the key listeners.

I found this example

```
on(keyPress "<Right>"){
gotoAndStop('underwriting');
}
```

on this page 
http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=97523.  How it would work is every time you press the right arrow key the gotoAndPlay function would be called. If you just want to go to a particular image and stop then you could use gotoAndStop. This would go to a particular frame and stop. Then you could click the right arrow again to go onto the next image in the gallery.

The keyPress method in the particular format showed above needs to be run in onEnterFrame.

To setup the OnEnterFrame function you need a listener. You could declare this in your constructor.

```
 addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
```

This is the On Enter frame if you put your keyPress in here every time a key is pressed this method will be run. 
 public function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void {

```
    }
```

I hope the code segments have been helpful and I have explained the various components in an easy way to follow. If you require further assistance please leave a comment so I can make changes

I found this for creating a slide show
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_BYMYgz6Qk

Comment: thank you for your reply, I have ten slides and I added keylistener and made a switch case if user press on right key the slide goto the next one and if he press on left the current slide the current slide replay from the beginning of the current slide, and I want this to be made for each slide but the problem that if I'm on the third slide it replay from the beginning, please advice.

Comment: if you are using gotoAndStop and its playing again you could always put a stop in the timeline insert an action and type in stop();. I can show you a visual demonstration if that will help.

Comment: I added a video on creating a slide show. Does that help at all.